# LuaTeX treats ^^M in \wlog differently

Tags: luatex, tex-core, logging

I am confused by the output of the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
\obeylines
\typeout{abc^^Muvw}
\wlog{ijk^^Mxyz}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

With PDFLaTeX or XeLaTeX, I get

```
abc^^Muvw
ijk^^Mxyz
```

But with LuaLaTeX, I get

```
abc
uvw
ijk
xyz
```

Why LuaTeX treats `^^M` in `\wlog` differently? Is the behaviour customizable in LuaTeX?

Comment: I cannot recreate your lualatex behavior

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Strange. I tested the code on latest MikTeX and TeXLive. Both gave the above output with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I can reproduce the OP's finding on my system (MacOS 12.3.1 "Monterey", MacTeX2022, LuaHBTeX 1.15.0, LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by-design: LuaTeX deliberately passes `^^M` (and `^^I` and `^^J`) as is'. From the LuaTeX manual:

> Output to the terminal uses `^^` notation for the lower control range ( < 32), with the exception of `^^I`, `^^J` and `^^M`. These are considered ‘safe’ and therefore printed as-is. You can disable escaping with `texio.setescape(false)` in which case you get the normal characters on the console.

Comment: Sorry, but just adding `\directlua{texio.setescape(false)}` to the code doesn't produce the same log text as PDFLaTeX. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: @L.J.R. I edited my answer pretty much immediately: the adjustment is to make other low chars act like `^^M` in LuaTeX, not to make `^^M` act as it does in pdfTeX.